# Can you say berachot in the lying position or in bed?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Are there any issues with saying berachot in the lying position? The reason I ask is it just always bothered me saying shema or Asher Yatzar in bed. If there are no issues then I shouldn't be bothered.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud ([Berakhoth 60b](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60b?lang=en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)), when discussing the blessing recited before going to sleep, uses the phrase "one who enters to sleep on his bed", perhaps implying that it would be inappropriate to wait until lying down:

> הנכנס לישן על מטתו אומר מ"שמע ישראל" עד "והיה אם שמוע", ואומר: ברוך המפיל
>   חבלי שינה על עיני...
>
> Who goes in to sleep upon his bed says from "Hear, O Israel" to "And it shall come to pass, if ye shall hearken diligently" ; then he says: "Blessed... Who makest the bands of sleep to fall upon mine eyes

However, the continuing passage is virtually explicit that the initial blessings upon arising are said before physically getting up:

> כי מתער אומר:
>   אלקי נשמה שנתת בי טהורה...;  כי שמע קול תרנגולא לימא: ברוך אשר נתן לשכוי
>   בינה להבחין בין יום ובין לילה; כי פתח עיניה לימא: ברוך פוקח עורים; כי
>   תריץ ויתיב לימא: ברוך מתיר אסורים; כי לביש לימא: ברוך מלביש ערומים; כי
>   זקיף לימא: ברוך זוקף כפופים; כי נחית לארעא לימא: ברוך רוקע הארץ על המים
>
> When he awakens he says : "O my G-d, the soul which Thou hast given me is pure... When he hears the cry of the cock let him say : "Blessed...Who hast given the cock intelligence to distinguish between day and night." When he opens his eyes let him say: "Blessed... Who openest the eyes of the blind." When he straightens himself and sits up let him say : "Blessed...Who loosest them that are bound."  When he has clothed himself let him say : "Blessed... Who clothest the naked." When he raises himself let him say : "Blessed... Who raisest up them that are bowed down." When he descends [from the bed] to the ground let him say: "Blessed... Who spreadest forth the earth above the waters."

See also [*Shulchan Arukh Orach Chaim* 63:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.63.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) where the recitation of *Shema* is explicitly allowed lying down. In fact, according to *Beth Shammai* ([*Mishna Berakhoth* 1:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.1.3?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)), with regard to the evening recitation of the *Shema*, lying down is actually mandated.)

Comment: Please note that at the same time the practice (and _p'sak_) with respect to the order and temporal placement of these _b'rachos_ changed - for some influential Ashkenazi _rishonim_ - the acceptability of reciting the _b'rachos_ in various positions and postures may have changed as well. I.e. The current acceptable practice may not match that found in the _g'mara_ for many European-descended practitioners.