Is it permissible to say personal prayers either sitting or laying down?
By "personal prayer" I mean expressing personal thoughts, hopes, and concerns, unlike the structured prayers found in the Siddur.

https://www.sefaria.org/Sichot_HaRan.68.7?lang=bi&with=all

@Sholom that opens up a new question - does one need to wear clothes? Until recently (according to halachic sources), people would be in the nude under the covers. Kings might be an exception tho

Why would sitting be a problem?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64287/can-you-say-berachot-in-the-lying-position-or-in-bed

@RabbiKaii The covers are considered clothes

@N.T. nonetheless, being nude under covers limits what one can and can't say according to strong halachic opinions. There's supposed to be a specific division between the top half of the body and the lower half, and covers alone do not achieve that

@RabbiKaii for that you can just use your arm to hold the covers tight.

Its not worse than saying modeh ani. Which you can say however u want, even with dirty hands.

@Shlomy because there's no shem Hashem

@RabbiKaii  and in his question hes using shem hashem? Im not even sure how his description is classified as a tfila
